# Why can't my code save files to C drive?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, webforms, c#-3.0

I am saving my image to a folder ***SiteImages*** that resides within project root but I want to place it on my C drive and want to save and access pictures from there i.e. **C;/SiteImages** but I can't figure out

Code: (Upload)

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/") + fileName);
```

Code: (Access)

```
string FilePath = new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/")).AbsoluteUri;
```

please help to make it work within C drive

UPdate: problem is with gridview picking picture from C drive now.

Old:

```
<img src='../SiteImages/<%# Eval("PersonalInfoEmployeePicture") %>' width="20" height="20" onmouseover="ShowFull(this)" onmouseout="ShowActual(this)" />
```

Comment: Don't do this .. it is not a windows application .. the path you provided for image must a http path .. it can be aceess like http:\\www.yourdomain.com\SiteImages\image1.jpg .. thats how http works ..

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as it is, right?

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs("C:\\SiteImages\\" + fileName);

string FilePath = "C:\\SiteImages\\" + fileName;
```

**UPDATED:**
As you said that you want it to be accessed as absolute URI, create a Virtual Directory in IIS pointing to SiteImages folder in C:. With that you can use `Server.MapPath` function to map the path into the folder you specified.

Comment: Saving worked sir but problem is with gridview as i mentioned, it doesn't pick pic in gridview as it used to

Comment: code: <img src='C:\SiteImages\<%# Eval("PersonalInfoEmployeePicture") %>'

Comment: Don't do this .. it is not a windows application .. the path you provided for image must a http path .. it can be aceess like http:\\www.yourdomain.com\SiteImages\image1.jpg .. thats how http works ..

Comment: @MoumitMondal can you rewrite the path ?

Comment: @Juventustech Have you tried creating Virtual Directory? If you have, you can use img tag as usual `<img src='/SiteImages/<%# Eval("PersonalInfoEmployeePicture") %>' ... />`. You cannot do refer the image using the code you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

just remove the begin `..` in image source

```
<img src='/SiteImages/<%# Eval("PersonalInfoEmployeePicture") %>' width="20" height="20" onmouseover="ShowFull(this)" onmouseout="ShowActual(this)" />
```

If you still using below code to save uploaded images

```
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/") + fileName);
```

Comment: and I am using this to upload images now, FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs("C:\\SiteImages\\" + fileName);

Comment: Then i don't think it will ever works .. until you explicitly host the `C:\SiteImages\ ` directory in IIS using different domainname and make image src to that domain name like `http:\\www.yourAnotherDomain.com\image1.jpg` ... The main point is your image should be hosted and should be accessible by http request .. like my profile image can be accessed by https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITuiU.jpg ..

Comment: I don't understand .. why you wants to save it to "C:\\SiteImages\\" .. not inside your website/webapplication directory ??

Comment: that is what the customer requires

Comment: What they want?? Is it that image should not be `accessible with out login` OR image should not get `deleted` OR no one can browse the `SiteImages` directory wherever can be it's location .. or something else.. If you describe your actual need  .. i can help you.. ;)

Comment: actually the picture stored within website folder is not accessible to RDLC report because I had hardcoded the path in rdlc expression

Comment: OMG!! .. Some bad thing you did boy.. and it's going to impact very hard .. Ok do one thing now .. Save the image in `both location` ..  the C Drive one will be used for RDLC and the website one will be used for image source ..