# Why my img src tag fails to load image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, web, webforms

I am using this to save images in C drive's folder

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.FileName);
FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs("C:\\SiteImages\\" + fileName);
```

and it works fine but problem is accessing the image in **img src** tag.

I am doing like this

```
<img src='/SiteImages/<%# Eval("PersonalInfoEmployeePicture") %>' width="20" height="20"onmouseover="ShowFull(this)" onmouseout="ShowActual(this)" />
```

but it only gives white black picture without any broken etc.

Comment: Can you share the code behind code? Where this tag is present inside a databound control?

Comment: I think src is point to a wrong folder, try change it to src='C:\\SiteImages\\<%# Eval("PersonalInfoEmployeePicture") %>'

Comment: @RahulSingh sir it's inside Grdview ITEM TEMPLATE

Comment: @Bayeni i did but doesn't work

Comment: what is returned by <%# Eval("PersonalInfoEmployeePicture") %>'? ensure that the emage name returned in exists in  SiteImages. if I were I would hard code one image and see if it displays, if does that will mean <%# Eval("PersonalInfoEmployeePicture") %>' is returning a image name that is not in C:\SiteImages

Comment: @Bayeni sir it returns picname.extension only from database

Comment: I have tried hardcoding like <img src='C:\\SiteImages\\image.jpg but didn't work

Comment: I have also tried hardcoding this <img src='file://C:/SiteImages/image.jpg'

but didn't work

Comment: @Juventustech - Hey so you have `SiteImages` folder in your web app project?

Comment: no it's C:/SiteImages

Comment: My upload control upload it to C:/SiteImages successfully but doesn't display in img src, i tried hardcoding the path but doesn't work even with D drive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't my code save files to C drive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772969/why-cant-my-code-save-files-to-c-drive)

Comment: mmm maybe u need src='C:\SiteImages\image.jpg'  :-) just replace \\ with \

Comment: @Juventustech - Hey for variety of reasons you should save your file in the web application project itself. Instead of saving it in a particular folder, add a folder to the web app project and it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get a chance to code and see but please try using the below code:

```
<img src='<%# "/SiteImages/" + Eval("PersonalInfoEmployeePicture") %>' width="20"       height="20"onmouseover="ShowFull(this)" onmouseout="ShowActual(this)" />
```